# How to add to my google map "add a placemark" button?

Tags: google-maps

I need to add an ability for users of my site to add new marks with text description. I see that Google map has such button, but I cannot find any description about adding this button to my map.

[image]

Comment: Which version of the maps API? 2 or 3?